# CDF looks OK but Integral of PDF does not sum to 1.0

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I defined a CDF as a function of another CDF of a well known probabilistic distribution. Now I want to obtain the PDF of the former CDF. To check if the PDF is correct I integrate it over the range and see if I got a value equal to 1.0. I don't. The CDF looks OK, tends to zero when the value approaches -Infinitty and tends to one as the value approaches +Infinity.
Here is the code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
(*Initial Input data*)
u11 = 1;
s11 = u11*1;
p1 = 0.1;
(*Initial CDF*)
 FS11[r_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[u11, s11], r]
(*Modified CDF*)
FS1[x_] := (1 - p1)*HeavisideTheta[x] + p1*FS11[x]
```

Plotting `FS1`I see no errors:

```
Plot[FS1[x], {x, -4, 4}, AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotRange -> Full]
```

However when I obtain the PDF

```
fS10[x_?NumericQ] = D[FS1[x], x]
```

and integrate it I get a value different that 1.0

```
NIntegrate[fS10[y], {y, -Infinity, +Infinity}]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you expect? Your CDF has a jump and then you try to define the PDF by numerical differentiation, That's just not going to work; there's no way to represent the delta spike you get from differentiation a unit step numerically. If you use `HeavisideTheta`, then symbolic differentiation gives you the `DiracDelta` you need. Or use `ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF",cdf},...]` to define a distribution in terms of its CDF.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit but even if I change `UniStep` for `HeavisideTheta`I get the same result or if I define `fS10[x_] := (1 - p1)*DiracDelta[x] + p1*fS11[x]` and `fS11[r_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[u11, s11], r]` when I `NIntegrate[fS10[y], {y, -Infinity, +Infinity}]` I get 0.1...

Comment: @SjoerdSmit regarding your second suggestion can you elaborate that please? Something like `FS1n[x_] = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", FS1[x]},...]` and then how to obtain the PDF?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use UnitStep or HeavisideTheta. The point is that a Dirac delta cannot be handled numerically. When treated numerically, `DiractDelta[x]` is as good as `0`.

Comment: The correct solution depends on what you want to do with this distribution.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok! I want to use it in a convolution integral, to get the CDF of Z=X+Y where X has a CDF given by FS1

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215715/881 if I'm on the right track....